# Why can't I access a company server via ssh from outside the network, while the server clearly has internet access via git/apt etc?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh, vpn

I use a linux (ubuntu) server inside a smallish company network to do general automated data processing, hosting of a mongodb server and i am also trying to run a dash app webserver.

For various reasons I would like this server to communicate with the outside world:

- setup jupyter kernels so that a small team can develop via ssh tunneling
- access the mongodb server via pymongo/ssh
- connect with web hosted services/databases

Now my IT department says this is only possible via VPN, which can only be installed on hardware managed by the IT department. They don't explain themselves very well and I am not experienced enough to set things up myself, so my questions are:

- Why would I need a VPN for ssh when the server in question is clearly able to communicate with the outside world (git clone, apt-get all work fine)? I don't know a lot about VPN or networking, so I just don't understand why some services need a VPN while others don't?
- What can I do to find out a possible workaround or test on the server why exactly ssh is not working? I have sudo rights.

Comment: If “various reasons” are in fact a business requirement, higher-ups will make it happen. If it isn’t, it’s not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why would I need a VPN for ssh when the server in question is clearly able to communicate with the outside world (git clone, apt-get all work fine)?

The server is able to communicate with the outside world - but that doesn't mean that the outside world is able to communicate with the server. It's actually pretty common outside of the business world too due to various forms of NAT. In your case it may also be an intentional firewall setup. The communication must be initiated from inside the network.

Why would you do that? In short: because people inside the organization are trustworthy and/or controllable to some extent to limit the attack surface, and outsiders are neither.

VPN connects you to the insiders' network and makes sure that you're actually authorized to connect. Possibility to have it only on company-issued hardware is a part of the "trustworthy and controllable" thing.

> What can I do to find out a possible workaround or test on the server why exactly ssh is not working? I have sudo rights.

It's called *"shadow IT"* and you shouldn't do it. As you've admitted you aren't experienced enough to understand why things are set up like this. That implies that you aren't knowledgeable enough to understand when it's safe to work around them. And that's okay, you don't have to be an expert at everything. Work with the experts, rather than against them.

Comment: +1 : Nice - "The server is able to communicate with the outside world - but that doesn't mean that the outside world is able to communicate with the server."

Answer (score 1):

> Why would I need a VPN for ssh when the server in question is clearly able to communicate with the outside world (git clone, apt-get all work fine)? I don't know a lot about VPN or networking, so I just don't understand why some services need a VPN while others don't?

It's more or less the same two reasons why your computer can reach other sites, but others cannot reach your computer.

1. The server might not have a "global" or "public" IP address (exactly like your home PC typically doesn't have one). If the server only has a "private" address, you literally have no way to send packets towards that server across the Internet – only the company's own network knows where that address goes, but your ISP does not. (It's like if you tried to ship something by specifying only the house number, but not the street nor the city nor the state.)

   But connecting to the company's VPN basically places you *within* the company's network; the VPN connection makes sure that all packets sent to the server's private address go through the company's VPN gateway, which knows exactly where to forward them.

   The server – or your PC – can still make *outbound* connections because the network's external gateway is set up to translate all private addresses into one of the public addresses that belong to the gateway, so inbound reply packets will be correctly delivered over the Internet to the same gateway (which then translates them back to the server's internal address).

   (While it's common for servers to have their own public IP addresses if they're *meant* to be publicly accessible, it's equally common to use private addressing for servers that are restricted-access. Public IPv4 addresses are scarce; a larger company might only have 32 or 128 or 512 of them, a smaller company might only have one.)
2. The server will likely have a *firewall* (packet filter) configured, or be placed behind a dedicated firewall. Even if the server has a public address that you could reach over the public Internet, it's still free to discard any packets it doesn't want – and given the state of today's Internet, many corporate networks deliberately block *all* inbound connections except a few specific kinds.

   For example, as soon as you allow inbound SSH connections on the standard port 22, you'll start receiving *hundreds if not thousands* of unwanted connection attempts per day. Even if the server is set up securely, those connections will flood the system logs and sometimes even hit the "concurrent connection" safety limits, preventing legitimate clients from logging in. So you either set up a system to auto-block bad clients, or decide to just block everything external.

   In most cases, the server can still make outbound connections because the firewall is *stateful* – it keeps track of each connection made and automatically allows reply packets back in *if* they correspond to a known active connection (IP addresses match, TCP ports match, etc).
3. All of the above.

> What can I do to find out a possible workaround or test on the server why exactly ssh is not working? I have sudo rights.

The only workaround I can recommend in this situation is "use the VPN". There are others, which involve making a long-lived outbound connection to somewhere else and tunneling back through it, but your IT team might extremely dislike them.

For reason #1 (no public address), just look at the server address you're connecting to – check if it's within one of the four specific ranges that are reserved for private addresses. (Also check whether same address is shown by `ip addr` while SSH'd to the server.)

For reason #2A (system-level firewall), look at the iptables & nftables rulesets on the server. Ubuntu might manage them using `ufw`, while the "raw" commands would be `iptables-save` and `nft list ruleset`.

For reason #2B (network-level firewall), check if you can install a packet capture tool on the server – tcpdump or termshark – and ask it to show packets coming from e.g. your home IP address. (You can also install the same tools on your own PC to be able to compare; Wireshark as a GUI version is available for every OS.)

If you then try to connect from home to that server, but the corresponding TCP packets do not show up on a packet capture *at* the server, then they got blocked by a firewall somewhere along the way.

Comment: ok, to clarify: if outbound connections work, i can access lets say an azure vm or a hosted database service via ssh/http or ftp from the server inside the network but not the other way round?

Comment: Generally yes, although FTP might not always work reliably through firewalls, and some database protocols might still be deliberately blocked as risky (e.g. there might be left-over blocks for outbound MS-SQL connections from the "SQL Slammer" days, and SMB3 even more so).

Answer (score 1):

When you connect from outside your company network, you use the public
IP address of your company. This address is actually that of the router
that stands between the local network and the internet.

So, in using SSH with this internet address, you're actually connecting
to the *company's router*, not to your own computer.

To expose your computer to the internet, the router must know that any
outside connection of a client to an SSH server is intended to be to
your computer. This is called
[Port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding).

You should talk to your network administrator and ask to set up
Port forwarding to your computer of SSH connections.
There are some security considerations involved, as computers connected
to the internet may very likely be attacked by hackers, which is why
you should consult with a knowledgeable person.